# Help me!! script not run in visualforce page

Tags: force.com

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSearch() {
    searchServer(
    document.getElementById("productCode").value,
    document.getElementById("productName").value,

    document.getElementById("season").option[document.getElementById("season").selectedIndex].value
    )
    }
</script>

<apex:actionFunction name="searchServer" action="{!runSearch}" rendered="result,debug,errors">
    <apex:param name="productCode" value=""/>
    <apex:param name="productName" value=""/>
    <!-- Picture -->
    <apex:param name="season" value=""/>
</apex:actionFunction>

<table cellpadding="2" cellspaceing="2">
    <tr>
        <td style="font-weight:bold;">Product Code<br/>
            <input type="text" id="productCode" onkeyup="doSearch()" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style="font-weidht:bold;">Product Name<br/>
            <input type="text" id="productName" onkeyup="doSearch()" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Picture -->
    <tr>
        <td>Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction()"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style="font-weidht:bold;">Season<br/>
            <select id="season" onchange="doSearch();">
                <option value=""></option>
                <apex:repeat value="{!Season}" var="sea">
                    <option value="{!sea}">{!sea}</option>
                </apex:repeat>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is my code.I don't know why script not run
I lean in this page 
http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/07/13/building-a-dynamic-search-page-in-visualforce/

help me please!!

Comment: Have you used Chrome or Firebug and their developer tools to see if any errors are thrown to the console?

Comment: Can you also post some snippets from your controller (e.g. your runSearch method)?

Comment: MyFunction isn't defined, so when you enter information into the Enter your name input you will receive an error.

Comment: Your actionFunction has a `rendered` attribute, I think you mean `rerender`